# Item Name won't pop up in display (space problem)

Tags: c++

Back to the cash register, every time I input an item name, it doesn't show the other words

I tried

```
cout<<"Enter  item "<<(i+1)<<" name \t\t: ";
std::cin >> l[i].itemName;
std::getline(std::cin, l[i].itemName);
```

which allowed me to input items with spaces. but in display (the receipt), if I inputed pizza and ice cream, the item that shows up is:

```
1.
2. Cream
```

Here's the display code:
how do I fix the item name problem?

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    cout<<"No. :  "<<l[i].id<<"\t"  "Item ID. :  "<<l[i].itemid<<"\t"   "Item Name :  "<<l[i].itemName<<" \t" "Quantity : "<<l[i].quantity<<" \n"  "Price per quantity :  Php"<<l[i].price<<"\n";
    cout<<"---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n";
    total += l[i].quantity*l[i].price;
}
```

Comment: please post a [mcve].

Comment: So your problem is how to input multi-word strings properly?

Comment: yep, sorry i dont really know how to do that TT